# Javascript inheritance - override super function

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I want to override a function from superclass to call the super function + additional code. How do i accomplish this?

```
function superClass(){
    this.superFunction = function(arg){
        //code
    }
}
function subClass(){
    this.superFunction = function(arg){
        //call super function()

        //aditional code bellow
        //...
    }   
}
subClass.prototype = new superClass();
```

Comment: In this case - `this.prototype.superFunction.call(this,param1,param2)`.

Answer (score 1):

The key is:

```
superClass.prototype.superFunction.call(this, arg);
```

But first, you're never attaching the `superFunction` to the prototype of `superClass` but rather only declare it as a simple public property:

```
function superClass(){
    this.superFunction = function(arg){
        // ...
    }
}

console.log(superClass.prototype);
> superClass {}
```

So to achieve the behavior you want:

```
function superClass(){

}
superClass.prototype.superFunction = function (arg) {
    console.log(arg+' from parent!');
}

function subClass(){

}
subClass.prototype = new superClass();

// At this point a 'superFunction' already exists
// in the prototype of 'subClass' ("Inherited" from superClass)
// Here, we're overriding it:
subClass.prototype.superFunction = function(arg){

    superClass.prototype.superFunction.call(this, arg);

    console.log(arg+' from child!');
}


var childCl = new subClass();
childCl.superFunction('Hello ');

> Hello from parent!
> Hello from child!
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use "call"

```
 this.superFunction = function(arg){
    return superClass.prototype.superFunction.call(this, arg);
};
```

using "call" you can pass in the "this" of the context you are in and the args you want to pass. By doing this, you can override the Class's method with the superClass method.

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality, perhaps you could add a bit more to make it more relevant?

Answer (score -1):

save a copy before you replace it.

```
function subClass(){
    var prevSuper = this.superFunction;
    this.superFunction = function(arg){
        //call super function()
        prevSuper(arg);
        //aditional code bellow
        //...
    }   
}
```